# Putting together a complex and changeable query to filter a table

Tags: django

I want to enable filtering on a table. Some of the filters are simple, eg a dropdown to select user. But others are more complex, eg the from date needs to display table rows that have a date that's greater than the filter date. And the search box should search multiple fields in the table.

[image: Filters on a table]
I started attacking the problem by using a lot of IF statements to built a search query based on the filters the user has applied. I then apply the query to model.objects.filter(a_string_built_depending_on_filters). So far so good but it looks like I'm going to have to start using Q() objects. I'm not sure if I can string together Q() queries in the same way.

```
@login_required
def entries_show_all(request):
    journal_entry_filter_form = JournalEntryFilterForm()
    line_item_filter_form = LineItemFilterForm()
    order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', '-journal_entry')
    filter_query = dict()
    url_params = ""
    if request.GET.get('user') and int(request.GET.get('user')):
        filter_query['journal_entry__user'] = str(request.GET.get('user'))
        url_params+='user='+urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(request.GET.get('user')))+'&'
    if request.GET.get('type'):
        filter_query['journal_entry__type'] = request.GET.get('type')
        url_params+='type='+urllib.parse.quote_plus(request.GET.get('type'))+'&'
    if filter_query:
        #logger.warning('Filter query:')
        #logger.warning(filter_query)
        #logger.warning('URL Params:'+url_params)
        line_items = LineItem.objects.filter(**filter_query).order_by(order_by)
    else:
        logger.warning('Filters have not been set')
        line_items = LineItem.objects.all().order_by(order_by)
    paginator = Paginator(line_items,20)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    line_items2 = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request,"journal/entries_show_all.html", {'line_items': line_items2, })
```

The URL Params variable is used in the template to add to the pagination links, so that the filter holds together while the user moves through pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have found [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html?highlight=pagination) and started implementing this add-on. Seems to do most of what I want it to.